# CRecordset::GetFieldValue exception "GetFieldValue operation failed on field ..." in c++ multithreading

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I am getting an exception "GetFieldValue operation failed on field ..." when calling GetFieldValue() function with CRecordset instance. It works fine with single thread, but causes error only with multi-threading. The following statements are being used. Any help?

To open the database:

```
CDatabase dbhandle;
dbhandle.OpenEx(dsn.c_str(), CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
```

To execute query and open recordset:

```
boost::shared_ptr<CRecordset> recordset(new CRecordset( &dbhandle ));
recordset->Open(AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, selectquery.c_str(), CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::executeDirect);
```

To read result:

```
recordset->GetFieldValue(fieldname.c_str(), value, SQL_C_CHAR);
```

Comment: I guess you do the reading (GetFieldValue) and creation (.. new CRecordset) in different threads? Multiple threads accessing the same CRecordset is not supported. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx6t3y0x.aspx 

quote: "When creating a multithreaded application, you should be very careful in using multiple threads to manipulate the same object. For example, using the same CRecordset object in two threads might cause problems when retrieving data;"

Comment: It uses same thread for recordset creation and reading purpose. Other threads also perform the same action in same table but with different records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the problem and fixed it. The exception arises because two different threads try to access the same `CDatabase` handle. `CDatabase` is not thread safe right now.

The solution is to implement the application level locking using `mutex`. Write the adapter class for `CDatabase` and perform lock/unlock for all actions.

```
// Define lock variable as instance
boost::mutex database_lock;

// Add the below line in each function which access database
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(database_lock);
```

Visit http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html to read more about locking.